# apt-get not working after upgrade to 18.04: "libzstd.so.1: No such file or directory"

Tags: apt, upgrade

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and  post the exact command you entered and the full output.

Comment: Looks like bug 1764858

Answer (score 1):

Does `apt` work? You can try using it instead of `apt-get`. Or, if you need `apt-get` specifically:

The error signifies that a library `libzstd.so` could not be found. If `apt` works, you can try installing that library:

`sudo apt install libzstd1`

Or, if that doesn't help, we can try making a symbolic link between another version of that library and the one that it's looking for. Try navigating to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, finding any file called `libzstd.so.1.3.3` or similar enough, and remembering its name.

Then, open a terminal by `CTRL+SHIFT+T`, and doing this set of commands:

1. `cd usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
2. `sudo ln -s "libzstd.so.1.3.3" "libzstd.so.1"` (where `libzstd.so.1.3.3` is name of a file you found)

Then, see if `apt-get` works.

Answer (score 0):

After installing from usb image to a pre-existing mdarray I had the same problem.  As suggested in another post, I copied the missing library file from another similar system and was able to complete the upgrade.

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 -> libzstd.so.1.3.3